# What is a working formula that can calculate to show if an appointment time has surpassed two hours by referencing the current time

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently tying up a work project in Google Sheets, but I'm stuck on an addition that I would like to add. I had an idea to show whether an input appointment time had surpassed a 2 hour window while referencing the current time. I tried the code below but I keep getting N/A returns or #error. Any help would be appreciated.

> "=IF(A2+TIME(2,0,0)<(TEXT(NOW()'HH:mm'), 'YES', 'NO')"

Basically if the input time in cell A2 plus two hours is less than the current time, it would state yes or no. I admit my knowledge although growing, is still a bit basic. Thanks for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Hi and Welcome! I posted my answer, let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Just make sure your input (A2) has the right date format like it is in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A2+(2/24)<now(), "YES", "NO")
```

[image: Example]